What does this command do?
In vim fandom wiki I found this command:
nnoremap \z :setlocal foldexpr=(getline(v:lnum)=~@/)?0:(getline(v:lnum-1)=~@/)\\|\\|(getline(v:lnum+1)=~@/)?1:2 foldmethod=expr foldlevel=0 foldcolumn=2<CR>

Could anyone help me to understand what the meaning is?
I think the foldexpr is set by the first getline OR (\\|\\|) the second, with something related to the previous search pattern but I couln't figure what the ~@/, the ?0 and ?1:2 mean.

Let's break it down:
(getline(v:lnum)=~@/)
    ?
        0
    :
        (getline(v:lnum-1)=~@/)\\|\\|(getline(v:lnum+1)=~@/)
            ?
                1
            :
                2

That abomination is an expression made of nested ternary operators, which are described under :help ternary and, more generally, in this Wikipedia page:
<condition> ? <return value if true> : <return value if false>


I couln't figure what means the ~@/

It means nothing because it doesn't exist. You actually have:

=~, a comparison operator that uses regular expressions (see :help =~),
@/, a regular expression pattern.


I couln't figure what means the ?0

Same as above. You actually have:

?, the first half of the ternary operator, between the condition and the return value if the condition is true,
0, the value to return if the condition before the ? is true.


I couln't figure what means the ?1:2

Same as above. You actually have:

?, the first half of the ternary operator, between the condition and the return value if the condition is true,
1, the value to return if the condition before the ? is true,
:, the second half of the ternary operator, between the value to return if the condition is true and the value to return if the condition is false,
2, the value to return if the condition before the ? is false.

Hard to read, hard to debug… nested ternary operators should be outlawed.
